# What are "cuir" and "velours" liaisons?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

While reading [the wiki article on French liaisons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28French%29#Liaison_errors), I came across this bit:

> **Cuir** (addition of erroneous liaisons in -t-):
>
> - *Tu peux-t-avoir*, instead of *tu peux‿avoir* (with /.z‿/).
>
> **Velours** (addition of erroneous liaisons in -z-):
>
> - *moi-z-aussi*.
> - *cent-z-euros* (100 €), instead of *cent‿euros* (with /.t‿/) — although *deux cents‿euros* (200 €) is correct (with /.z‿/).

It's pronounced *peux-t-avoir* ?? Or they're saying that's wrong? I'm having a hard time following this. And *Moi-z-aussi*… is that how it should pronounced?

I guess I'm just now learning the finer points of liaisons — prior to now I had just been going by basic spelling rules.

Comment: Ces deux exemples montrent des erreurs à ne pas faire !! On les entend parfois dans les conversations familières. Je connaissais l'expression *faire un cuir*, très soutenue, employée dans les milieux académiques ou liés au théâtre, et je n'ai pas de souvenir de *velours* pour caractériser une liaison fautive.

Comment: J'ai toujours dit (et entendu) « Pataquès » pour l'un comme pour l'autre.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misunderstanding from the OP about the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Well, are these common mispronunciations? I mean, why on earth would someone put a *t* in the middle of *peux avoir*? Why does the article bring this up at all?

Comment: @M42, les _pataquès_ sont, stricto sensu, une autre forme d'erreur de liaison (utiliser _s_ ou il faut _t_ ou réciproquement, donc certains cuirs et certains velours, mais pas tous, sont aussi des pataquès); par métonymie, on utilise aussi pataquès pour n'importe quelle faute de laison.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Merci pour l'info, je ne connaissais pas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the article mentions, these are erroneous liaisons ! So don't make them. The idea is that, for instance, by analogy with vous aussi or deux cents euros, the speaker puts a liaison that etymologically shouldn't be there.

Of course, as always, "erroneous" is in the eye of the beholder. Some liaisons which started out as erroneous are now standard. I believe this is the etymology of the /z/ in vas-y (c.f. va à...) and the /t/ in pense-t-il, for instance. Still, most native French speakers won't make the cuir or velour errors in spontaneous informal speech, so you shouldn't try to imitate them, even if you want to sound slangy. (My understanding is that the errors arise when someone is trying to talk more sophisticatedly than necessary and hasn't thought through properly which words take liaison.)

By the way, liaisons, and erroneous liaisons, also occur in British English -- where r is not pronounced word-finally, except before a vowel. (My mothe(r), my mothe-r-ate a biscuit.) For instance, if you listen to Oasis's  "Champagne Supernova," he pronounces the word "supernover" before the phrase "in the sky" which starts with a vowel.