# Conveying "out of the blue" (completely unexpected)

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

If something happens out of the blue, it is completely unexpected; e.g.

> I hadn’t heard from Georges for years; then I got a letter out of the blue.

Google Translate gives

> Je n'avais pas entendu parler de Georges depuis des années; puis j'ai reçu une lettre à l'improviste.

Can the idiom *À l'improviste* convey the meaning of *out of the blue*? Can it be used colloquially?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No single expression can translate **out of the blue**.

Depending on the context, potential idiomatic ones might be:

- Il est sorti **de nulle part**
- il est arrivé **d'on ne sait pas où** (ou le velours courant : **d'on ne sait-z-où**)
- Il l'a sorti **de son chapeau**
- Il a débarqué **à l'improviste**
- C'est arrivé **d'un coup** / **subitement**
- Il nous l'a annoncé **de but en blanc**
- Il l'a décidé **sans crier gare**
- Il lui a demandé **à brûle-pourpoint** (outdated)

In your case, *puis j'ai reçu une lettre à l'improviste* is odd because letters are delivered at expected times<sup>1</sup>. That would have better worked with a phone call: *puis un jour, il m'a téléphoné à l'improviste*.

For a letter, you might perhaps say: *et puis il s'est remanifesté un jour en m'envoyant une lettre*.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Damien's spot on suggestion proves me wrong... Une lettre peut tomber du ciel !</sub>

Comment: J’ai souvent entendu « Il est arrivé d'on ne sait où » (sans le *pas* et sans liaison) prononcé parfois dans un dialogue animé « d'on ne sait-z-où », sans que cela soit très choquant. Je ne sais pas si « par surprise » conviendrait au contexte anglais.

Comment: Soudain, la lettre est arrivée ! —  La lettre est arrivée soudainement —  La lettre est arrivée impromptue… — La lettre est arrivée … complètement imprévisible/inattendue.

Comment: « … (ou le *velours courant* : … » expression vernaculaire du Québec ?

Comment: @Personne Pourquoi du Québec ?  On l'entend partout, non ?

Comment: C'est la première fois que je la lis, à part « le petit Jésus en culotte de velours » (un vin, un mets délicieux) ou « c'est du velours » pour parler une action qui se déroule sans accrocs … « langue de velours » est plutôt connoté lèche-···bottes  … "(ou *l'usage courant*  … " me vient spontanément à l'esprit, sans le support des papilles :-)

Comment: @Personne La deuxième fois ;-)  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/what-are-cuir-and-velours-liaisons#comment21426_12119

Answer (score 5):

En complément des propositions déjà citées, une traduction possible qui reprend l'image du bleu :

> Une lettre (de lui) m'est tombée du ciel

Autre possibilité, mais plus datée et pas avec la bonne couleur :

> Une lettre (de lui) m'est parvenue du diable Vauvert

Comment: Une couleur se cache quand même dans *diable Vauvert* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai. corrigé. On en revient aux verts pâturages d'une autre question récente.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt after three years, for the sentence of the question at least !

> I hadn’t heard from Georges for years; then I got a letter out of the blue.

> La lettre de Georges est arrivée comme un coup de tonnerre ; je ne m'y attendais pas du tout.