# L'hiver est venu imprévu

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

En russe on utilise l'expression "l'hiver est venu imprévu" ("зима пришла нежданно") en parlant d'un événement complètement prévisible auquel personne ne s'est préparé (l'hiver et l'insouciance profonde étant considérés comme deux choses profondément russes.)

Comment est-ce qu'on exprime la même idée en français ? Y a-t-il des expressions particulières ?

Comment: « L'hiver est venu *soudain*. » (ou, *soudainement*) pour garder la structure de la phrase et le verbe proposés ou « l'hiver est arrivé *brusquement*. » https://www.deepl.com/translator#ru/fr/%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%0A utilise *à l'improviste* par défaut et propose d'autres traductions intéressantes quand on clique sur ‘improviste’, dont « L'hiver est arrivé à la surprise générale » qui correspond bien au problème soulevé par la question.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/conveying-out-of-the-blue-completely-unexpected

Comment: L'arrivée de l'hiver était imprévue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pourrait le rendre en français par :

> L'hiver nous est tombé dessus à l'improviste.

Il se trouve que l'un des exemples d'utilisation du TLFi ressemble beaucoup à ce dicton russe :

[Improviste](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/improviste):

> De manière soudaine, imprévue. *Arriver, survenir, entrer, prendre à l'improviste.*
> ...
> • ...un printemps gai, charmant, exquis, tout frais débarqué de la nuit sans avoir averti de sa venue, en bon provincial qui arrive du midi, tombe sur les gens **à l'improviste** et s'amuse de leur surprise. Courteline, *Ronds-de-Cuir*, 1893, 1<sup>er</sup>tabl., I, p. 20.

Et voici une « vraie » occurrence de l'expression [sur ce blog](http://lemondesansschopenhauer.blogspot.com/2008/12/rafrachissement.html) :

> Mardi vingt-trois décembre deux mille huit. Neuf heures vingt du matin (heure française, deux heures vingt du même matin). **L'hiver nous est tombé dessus à l'improviste.** Avant-hier, il faisait vingt-cinq degrés en plein soleil, je me promenais en short. Hier soir, il faisait zéro degrés, avec des moufles. La Chine ne plaisante pas avec son calendrier.

Answer (score 1):

En français ce n'est pas idiomatique ;

- L'hiver nous a pris de court.
- Nous nous sommes laissés prendre de court par l'hiver.
- L'hiver est arrivé sans qu'on y soit préparé.

Comment: @Zéhontée Bonteuse Vous avez raison. J'étais passé à côté du sens...

Comment: Cela pourrait être rendu aussi en condensant en quelque sorte la troisième proposition de LPH en "l'hiver est survenu, impréparé"

Comment: @Zéhontée Bonteuse Je vais en rester à un commentaire. Je voudrais également dire qu'une des meilleures analogies que l'on puisse trouver à cette expression russe en français se trouve dans la fable de la "Cigale et la Fourmi"(la Fontaine) "La cigale se trouva fort dépourvue lorsque l'hiver fut venu"

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker En fait il y a de bonnes chances qu'il s'agisse finalement de l'interpétation [initiale](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/44587/1) dont vous parliez:/