# Orthographe "zamicalement" ?

Tags: orthographe

Je suis tombé sur le poème "[Histoire de Mlle Manon](http://www.miscellanees.com/v/vade01.htm)" de J.-Joseph Vadé.

Dans la première strophe, on peut lire :

> *Qui veut savoir l'histoire entière,
>
> De mamselle Manon la couturière,
>
> Et de monsieur son cher amant,
>
> Qui l'aimait zamicalement.*

Sait-on pourquoi l'auteur a écrit "zamicalement", et non "amicalement"?

Comment: Lien ou pointeur vers le poème?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un *[velours](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/what-are-cuir-and-velours-liaisons)*, une liaison incorrecte que devait faire mamselle Manon ou son amant.

On trouve de très nombreux autres *cuirs* et *velours* dans ce poème :

> *Ce jeune homme-ci, **t**'un beau dimanche,*

> *A sa santé ? dit-y, **z**oui dà*

> *Qu'avec eux **t**'il est **z**engagé.*

> *D'aller faire un tour **t**'en prison.*

> *Ah ! voyez **t**'un peu l'injustice*

> *Sachant cela, Manon **z**habile,*

> *Pour lui raconter **z**en pleurant*

> *A Fontainebleau **z**elle arrive,*

> *Sus vot' respect, est **z**engagé.*

> *Il ne serait point **z**enrôlé,*

> *Puis lui fit donner mil **z**écus,*

L'auteur accentue le côté humoristique de l'histoire en utilisant une représentation phonétique un peu caricaturale de la langue populaire. Certaines de ces liaisons peuvent parfois s'entendre encore aujourd'hui comme *mil zécus* (*mille z'euros*).

Comment: TIL - AJA (?) :-)

Comment: @Frank [AJA](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=63500995#63500995) :-)

Comment: Zut. Bien tenté quand même, non? :-)

Comment: *cent-z-euros* assez souvent entendu, oui.

Comment: @XouDo Ou *entre quat'z'yeux*.

Comment: Dans la troisième citation: Qu'avec eux t'il est zengagé, 
le "t'" n'a-t-il pas la même fonction ?

Comment: @Hippo Oui, je le graisse.